# Spring Security w/LDAP Logout can't remove session

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap, logout

I'm using spring-boot-starter-security' version: '2.0.0 to secure a REST API.
Also, I'm login to an LDAP server. My login works fine, and the browser asks user/pass when I put an endpoint with authentication configuration.
The problem is when I performed the logout, I can re-enter that endpoint that needs to authentication, I mean, If a request a secure endpoint, the user/pass are required. If I login ok, the API shows the result of the endpoint, but if I perform the logout, the logout show me that was successful and I request the secure endpoint again, but the result is showed without login.
Also, I configured 2 max session, and when I perform two logouts, I can't login again because I received the error of max sessions.
So in some way, my logout is not working well.

This is my code:

```
@Configuration
```

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

```
    http.
            httpBasic()
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/about/**","/hello/**","/logout/**","/logout-success","/login/**").permitAll() //Allow to all to this url
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .requestCache()
            .requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
            .maximumSessions(2).expiredUrl("/login").maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
            .and()
    ;

    http.csrf().disable();
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

    //logout
    http.logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success");

}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {


    String ldapURL = "ldaps://xxxx";

    auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userSearchFilter("xxx")
            .userSearchBase("xxxx")
            .groupSearchBase("xxxx")
            // .groupSearchFilter("member={0}")
            .contextSource()
            .url(ldapURL)
            .port(xxx)
            .managerDn("xxxx")
            .managerPassword("xxxx")
    ;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found different theories about this, the most concurrent is that one that says that you can't perform a valid logout with the "Basic" configuration:

```
http.httpBasic()
```

So, the solution is to use a form page to provide the authentication or the `.formLogin()` provide by Spring.